# How do I use DrawerLayout to display over the ActionBar/Toolbar and under the status bar on KitKat?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-4.4-kitkat, material-design, android-toolbar

I've problems with implementing this guidelines in Kitkat. On Lollipop everything looks ok:
[image: Lollipop]

But on Kitkat Toolbar does not have any top padding:
[image: Kitkat]

I can fix this with https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint library using:

```
SystemBarTintManager.SystemBarConfig config = tintManager.getConfig();
mainView.setPadding(0, config.getPixelInsetTop(false), config.getPixelInsetRight(), config.getPixelInsetBottom());
```

But I feel that I'm doing something wrong. Do you have any good practices how to achieve this effect on KitKat?

Answer (score 0):

Move current layout resource in `layout-v21` folder to have it as it is on the first screenshot. Then try to create new layout resource that will have just a placeholder view of same [height of the status bar](http://goo.gl/Y4Xcde)

Hierarchy should be following:

```
--Top layout
  --<view layout_height="25dip"...>
  -- Toolbar
  -- the rest of the views
```

Using view аbove your `Toolbar`, will not push it behind the status bar, as it is on second screenshot and will mimick the padding you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Do you have fitsSystemWindow set to true? Setting it to false will bring the toolbar back under the status bar.

The effect you see for Kitkat is because you have translucent status bar set and fitting to System Window goes underneath it.

For example, in your layout XML file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/action_bar"/>

    <!-- YOUR CONTENT HERE -->

    <!-- YOUR NAVIGATION VIEW HERE -->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding code or reference.